# xargs Behavior : Semantics or Bug?

Tags: shell, command-line, zsh

Wanting to push a number of directories onto the stack, I ran:

`echo ~/{Desktop,Downloads,Movies} | xargs pushd`
and encountered `xargs: pushd: No such file or directory`

Brace expansion is not the cause of the mismatch between what I have in mind and what happens because `echo ~/Desktop | xargs pusdh` results in the same error.

As a point of comparison, `echo ~/Desktop | xargs cd` changes directory as one would expect.

What's going on here?

Comment: I can't explain why echo foo | xargs pushd doesn't work, but certainly trying to give pushd a list won't work, because it only takes one argument.

Comment: it was `xargs` complaining that `pushd` isn't found. `pushd` is not an external command. it is a `shell builtin` command.

Answer (score 1):

It's semantics, the equivalent statement should be:

```
pushd $(echo ~/{Desktop,Downloads,Movies})
```

After my experiment, the behavior of builtin command is like

```
#!/bin/sh

    function pushd()
    {
        accept input from $1, $2, $3.....

        # Builtin will not read from stdin! So you can't use pipe.
    }
```

The builtin command should be viewed as **shell function**.

**[Edit]**

The command 'pushd' in zsh is implemented together with 'cd', it only accept one argument.
So you can't push a number of directories in single statement. 
[source is there](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Src/builtin.c#L104)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `xargs cd` does what you expect? I'd be surprised! `xargs` will call a binary, but `pushd` is not - run `type pushd` if you want confirmation. `cd` and `pushd` don't make much sense as external binaries.

You'll need to capture the directories in a variable, and call `pushd` in a for loop in the shell process itself, rather than from `xargs`, which is a child process of the shell, and hence any directory state modified by `xargs` or its children won't pass up to the parent shell.